# Best way to get pull requests moved to another branch in git

Tags: git, github, merge

I have two branches, `master` and `dev`, and `master` should be a subset of `dev`. I have some commits that were made to `master` that I need moved to `dev`. However, some of the bad commits in `master` happened between other valid commits.

So it currently looks something like this:

```
master
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H - I

dev
A - B - - - - - E - - - G 
                          \
                            - - - J - K - L
```

But I need to get it to look like this:

```
master
A - B - - - - - E - - - G

dev
A - B           E       G
      \       /   \   /   \
        C - D       F       H - I - J - K - L
```

So in essence, I need to get `C-D`, `F`, and `H-I` moved from `master` to `dev`.

Basically, if I do a diff between `master` and `dev`, I need to pull over from `master` everything that is not in `dev`, and remove it from `master`.

It's a bit of a mess I know, mostly because we changed processes mid-stream. And to be honest, I'm trying to figure out how it got in this state to begin with. I'm not even sure at which point `dev` was branched off `master`.

So I'm just trying to figure the best way to clean up the mess at this point, and going forward, this shouldn't be an issue (now that we've "fixed" our process).

I've looked at `cherry-pick`, `merge`, and `rebase`, but I'm not sure which is appropriate here. I original was thinking `cherry-pick`, but since `master` should be a subset of `dev`, I was wondering if a `merge` or `rebase` is more appropriate here.

Also, just FYI, no one is working directly from either of these branches, and are working from their own forks, if that makes a difference in the solution.

**Update**:

So I did `git log` of `master` and `dev`:

```
git checkout master
git log --graph --oneline --all --abbrev-commit --decorate > ../master.txt
git checkout dev
git log --graph --oneline --all --abbrev-commit --decorate > ../dev.txt
```

And then did a comparison of the two graphs. This gave me a much better (and fortunately, much cleaner) picture of what had happened:

```
--->*   de80f1b (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merge pull request #168 from nebula101/support-lf-newlines
    |\  
    | * 8b6e985 (origin/pr/168) Add support for the LF line ending
    * |   b966002 Merge pull request #170 from nebula101/fc_alphanumeric
    |\ \  
    | * | 7bf0c25 (origin/pr/170) Add NNID
    | * | 060671d Add XBox360 and PSN to fc tool
    * | |   8089053 Merge pull request #169 from nebula101/small-changes
    |\ \ \  
    | * | | 7ef0317 (origin/pr/169) Update noticeboard header text
    | * | | ebe7d80 Add festive avatars
    | * | | 06dc673 Add 'Austria' to the list of countries
    | * | | e04d1a5 Fix a small typo
    | * | | d08d254 Fix images in view_view.asp
    | * | | 761c09c Fix items_list.asp
    | * | | 45096b7 Add Halloween avatars
    | * | | c05806f Fix age in profiles
    | * | | 5afdcbd Fix a typo in noticeboard_responses.asp
    | * | | e254a33 Chenge 'CNB edit should alert users' default
    | | |/  
    | |/|   
--->| | | * 3e3e829 (origin/dev, dev, AngelWings666-master) Merge pull request #181 from Quintinius/master
    | | | *   2165f08 (Quntinius-master) Merge pull request #183 from jeradrose/dev
    | | | |\
    ....
```

Basically, the only difference are the lines marked with `--->`, and the `HEAD` for `master` is on the top line, and the `HEAD` for `dev` is that bottom marked line.

In other words, the only thing done is that three pull requests (`8b6e985`, `7ef0317`, and `7bf0c25`) were merged to `master` instead of `dev`.

I think the view on GitHub was confusing me, because the commits made as part of those pull requests were made earlier (chronologically), but they didn't get committed until at the end when it was merged.

So what do I need to do to get those three pull requests moved to `dev`? I know how to move the `HEAD` of master back prior to these commits, just not sure the best way to get those merge pull requests over to `dev`.

Comment: I'm confused by all the up-and-down motion in your drawings, and the fact that you've labeled the branches that way with letters (A, B, etc) that are the same on `master` and `dev` yet have different parents: `E` has one single parent in both cases, but it's sometimes `D` and sometimes `B`.

Comment: There are no commits listed that have both `master` and `dev` as the parent. In the `dev` diagram, I am showing both `master` (top path) and `dev` (bottom path), to show that dev contains commits that originated in both `master` and `dev`. As far as the up & down in the "what it should look like" diagram, I'm also confused on how it got in this state, but regardless, this is the way it needs to be to accurately reflect what's actually in production -- that is, C, D, F, H, and I are not in production, but are in the `master` branch, and this is what I'm trying to clean up.

Comment: I'm still confused.  Commits don't have branches!  Commits have parent commit IDs, in the form of "true name" SHA-1s.  A branch name resolves to one single commit, e.g., `branch` might resolve to `222c4dd303570d096f0346c3cd1dff6ea2c84f83`.  That SHA-1 is the "true name" of the commit, and that commit has some parent ID(s) that tell you how the commit was created.  Those are immutable—you can make a *copy* of the commit with something(s) changed (that's what `cherry-pick` does), but that gets you a different commit, with different "true name" SHA-1.

Comment: Can a branch have commits though? I see what you're saying, and I admit I still don't have a solid grasp of how git works beneath the surface -- you obviously do. But don't get too hung up on the accuracy of the diagrams. Basically, `master` and `dev` currently have the commits as shown in the first diagram (according to GitHub), and I need to update them to the commits as shown in the second diagram.

Comment: Branches make commits "reachable": you can draw a graph (a graph theory type, Directed Acyclic Graph) of commits, with each commit a graph-node and its parent(s) pointing to other nodes, and then branch labels are the way you choose a starting point to walk the resulting graph.  Perhaps the diagrams are a github thing (I don't use github, just raw git).  Anyway, in general, if you have a graph you don't like and want to draw a new different one, the way to do this is with `cherry-pick` and (where needed) `merge`.  `git rebase -i` is just a shell script that runs those commands, for instance.

Comment: @torek Thanks, I think I'm getting closer to figuring out what's going on. I've updated the OP with quite a bit more info, so let me know your thoughts based on that. I think the solution is now much more straight-forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I know nothing of github, but to do this in your own local repo:

First, let's make sure there are markers—branch or tag names—on the pull-request commits, which are the ones just "before" the merge commit that brings them in, on the "right" side of the graph-log output.  There are three of those (numbers 169, 170, and 168 in a slightly odd order).  They're commits `8b6e985` (#168), `7bf0c25` (#170), and `7ef0317` (#169).

As it happens, they all have nice markers already, `origin/pr/168`, `origin/pr/170`, and `origin/pr/169`.  So step 1 is: check that labels exist, they do, done.

Now, let's fix `master` and then force-push the result back to `origin` (this assumes no one else has picked these up, or if they have, they know how to recover from the force-push):

```
git status            # make sure everything is clean
git show master~3     # make sure this is the right commit
```

Assuming these look right, let's get on `master` and tell git to reset it (with `--hard`) to `master~3`, i.e., back it up three left-hand-side parent commits:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard master~3
```

We've now "removed" the three merge commits from branch `master`, by making the label point three nodes further back in the graph.  Those three merge commits are no longer accessible by the names `HEAD` or `master`.  They're still accessible by the names `origin/master` and `origin/HEAD` but we are about to change that:

```
git push -f origin master  # anyone else using this is out of luck
```

Assuming `origin` allows this kind of force-push, it also now has the three merge commits inaccessible (and is likely to garbage collect them quickly).  This also changes our copy of `origin/master` at least, and probably `origin/HEAD` too, so now we can't see the merges (although they are still in there and will stick around for ~90 days due to reflog entries).

---

Aside: what if that doesn't work?  If the remote repo dis-allows force-push, you will have to "revert the merges".  This can be done with `git revert`, it's just a fair bit annoying as it makes later re-merging much harder.  Let's leave that out of this answer. :-)

---

Last, you want to make *new* merges to bring those commit-chains into `dev`.  So get onto branch `dev`:

```
git checkout dev
```

and then perform the merges.  There may be some more-automatic method you can use with pull requests and github, but this will do the trick:

```
git merge origin/pr/169  # bring in pull request 169's chain of commits
# do any fixing-up required, here - usually the merge will just work
# automatically and make a commit for you

git merge origin/pr/170  # bring in #170's single commit
# and fix-up if needed here, too

git merge origin/pr/168  # bring in #168's single commit
# and again here
```

In fact, if you like, you can merge all three at once with an "octopus merge".  Instead of three separate merge commands, you'd use one:

```
git merge origin/pr/169 origin/pr/170 origin/pr/168
```

Octopus merges are described (albeit not very well) in the [git-merge documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html).

Answer (score 0):

### First checkout the `master` branch:

`git checkout master`

### Then view the log to see the branch's commits:

`git log`

You will now see your commits listed, along with the hash for each commit:

> commit a0b6aa63955aa4dc9a2154e0a0de3b2e8ee6bef2 Author: Kevin Bowersox
>    Date:   Mon Nov 25 09:51:14 2013 -0500
>
> ```
> Commit to update
> ```
>
> commit d132fc724a7f749168a95383a3b376b1c4f699ef Author: Kevin Bowersox
>    Date:   Mon Nov 25 09:34:40 2013 -0500
>
> ```
> removed interceptor
> ```

### Copy the hash of the commits you want to move to `dev`:

.  For example the second commits hash is: `d132fc724a7f749168a95383a3b376b1c4f699ef`

### Now switch to the `dev` branch:

`git checkout dev`

### Then use cherry-pick to selectively merge the commit from master

`git cherry-pick d132fc724a7f749168a95383a3b376b1c4f699ef`